# How create combined cucumber plugin report from several reports produced in parallel by maven surefire plugin?

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

I am required to run cucumber tests in parallel (by using maven surefire multiple jvms, forkCount) - 
and the resultant report to be equivalent to a report created by running the tests sequentially.

I am using cucumber v3.
cucumber v4 allows tests to be run in parallel using a single runner with a combined resultant report- however my attempts with v4 have not enabled me to run multiple JVMs with a single runner / produce a single report.

Can you clarify/advise whether there is an alternative/simpler method of doing this to the below? i.e.
is it necessary to create the individual reports and merge them?
Can you clarify that cucumber-jvm 4 does not allow forking of multiple jvms to produce a single report?
The command I have used to run the tests sequentially is:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin junit:target/report.xml --plugin json:target/report.json"
```

In order to run tests in parallel I have created several testrunners each running in a different jvm and
each running several features and outputting (using the report plugins) to different xml and json reports.

In order to combine the reports I am intending to merge the individual xml and json reports.

Answer (score 0):

My Cluecumber Report plugin can actually do this as it merges all existing Cucumber json files into one report.
https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin

Comment: Is the combined report json format (which is what we need) or html? We also would like combined junit xml. thankyou

Comment: The Cluecumber report is html.